# Old Meta.SE Stars

Tags: script, design

## About

This userscript reverts the design of the [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com) buttons:

New design:

[image: New design]

With script:

[image: With script]

It was inspired by [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250479/i-want-the-old-good-star-back/250480) on [Meta Stack Exchange](//meta.stackexchange.com/).

## Download

You can download the script from [Greasy Fork](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/8355-old-meta-se-stars) ([Direct Link](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/8355-old-meta-se-stars/code/Old%20MetaSE%20Stars.user.js)) or [view the source code](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/8355-old-meta-se-stars/code).

## Installation

See the [script](/questions/tagged/script) tag wiki for details on userscript installation.

## History

See the [Greasy Fork changelog](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/8355-old-meta-se-stars/versions).

## Contact

Please post bug reports or feature requests on this page as an answer or comment.